# Sending an email via PHP error, with CPanel error

Tags: php

I have the following code to send an email.

```
<?php

    $NowDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $subject = "test subject";
    $message ="test message";
    $emailFrom = "noone@noone.net";
    $EmailAddress = "myemail@gmail.com";

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: My Site <".$emailFrom.">\r\n";
    $headers .= "To: <".$EmailAddress.">\r\n";
    mail($EmailAddress,$subject,$message,$headers);

    ?>
```

It runs successfully but the email doesn't getting sent with the following error listed in CPanel.

How do I go about resolving this?

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 CV=no: SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 550 Messages should have one or no To headers, not 2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `To` header. The first parameter of the `mail` function writes that header value. With it assigned in the header as well you send 2 `to`s which causes the error.

So remove:

```
$headers .= "To: <".$EmailAddress.">\r\n";
```